# Using 'Push to deploy' with shallow clones in git

Tags: git, deployment

I want to use the '[push to deploy](https://github.com/blog/1957-git-2-3-has-been-released)' feature introduced in Git 2.3 to deploy my web application. At the same time, I am wary of placing my entire git history on the server. I tried creating a shallow clone, and I was able to push to the shallow repository without any issues. Will this create any issues in future (for example, when updating a file whose last modification is not included in the shallow history?)